# Doctrine relation between entities based on a field value

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a problem with Doctrine 2 & Symfony.

I have a `User` entity, and three entities `Example1`, `Example2`, `Example3` I want to link with.

I would like to define a many2one relation between `User` and one of these three classes `Example1`, `Example2`, `Example3`, basing it on the value of `$relation_type` and `$parent` in `User`.

I was thinking to define an abstract class `Player` so `Example1`, `Example2`, `Example3` can extend from it, but I do not know how to go on ...

Any suggestions?

```
class User
{
    /* ... */
    private $relation_type;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Player
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Player")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;

}

class Player
{

}

class Example1 extends Player
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Player` is an abstract class then you can mark it as a mapped superclass with the `@MappedSuperClass` annotation. 
Check also [the Doctrine2 documentation chapter **6.1. Mapped SuperClasses**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) for more details.

```
<?php
/** @MappedSuperclass */
class Player
{
    //common properties
}
```

And now you can extend `Player` in your subclass:

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class Example1 extends Player
{
    //example1 specific properties.
}
```

Using mapped superclasses comes with its limitations. Read the documentation carefully to understand what is possible and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for STI which is basically an implementation for polymorphic data.

If I correctly understood your use-case I would recommend the following **Structure**

```
users[id, ..]
| 1-2-M
players[id, type, user_id, ..]
```

(*You could go further and create +1 table for each of the Examples to store specific data)

In **Doctrine/Symfony** that would translate into

```
<?PHP
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User {
}
```

-

```
<?PHP 
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="players")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "Example1" = "AppBundle\Entity\Players\Example1",
 *     "Example2" = "AppBundle\Entity\Players\Example2",
 *     "Example3" = "AppBundle\Entity\Players\Example3",
 *     "undefined" = "Player"
 * })
 */
abstract class Player
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profiles", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
protected $user;
}
```

-

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Example1 extends Player implements PlayerInterface
{
}
```

- http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html
- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Cristian, but what about **Class Table Inheritance** ?

Comment: CTI could do the job as well from what I can tell from the specs. My recommendation was only based on previous experience with STI. I guess as long as you use a polymorphic table you there's more than one way to implement the solution.